# Find specific part of string based on input - PHP regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following text:

```
  [[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_original","fid":"19125","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"480","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"480"}}]]

Sed iaculis, nisl vel accumsan condimentum, orci felis congue pede, nec pharetra quam ante nec ligula.

  [[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_original","fid":"16145","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"480","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"480"}}]]
```

I want to select the first paragraph of the text (section in brackets), based on the fid (19125).

This is my current regexp:

```
[\[].[^;]*[\]\)]]
```

But right now it will find both occurrences. I'd like to adjust this so it only gets the one with the correct fid (19125).

Comment: Why not just use `json_decode` and get the value?

Comment: @ctwheels I think the OP means the whole code block (two JSON strings and the text between them) is the input.

Comment: @mingos that makes sense, thanks for clarifying

Comment: You could just use `\[{2}{.*"fid"\s*:\s*"19125".*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add in the id to your regex. I've slightly change the regex so that `[^;]*` turned into `[^;]*"fid":"19125"[^;]*`. Which is roughly comparable to just doing a contains within each match to see if fid equals 19125.

`[\[].[^;]*"fid":"19125"[^;]*[\]\)]]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TiGoON/1)